# How to handle route timeout when Redis is doing a massive DEL+SET?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, redis

One of my routes (`overview_route`) is calling a numerous amount of model operations that is *normally* handled by my method caching in Redis. However, when a new/updated records is saved into the PG, I have a SideKiq job that will handle the the change in data by deleting the Redis keys that needs to be updated and then call our methods to cache it back into Redis. During this rebuild of Redis, if someone tries to reach `overview_route` it will hit the 30 second timeout termination (could take 1-3 minutes to run).

Example what typically happens:

```
User A will go to route `overview_route` when everything in redis is 
cached -- which will allow the page to be served quickly.

User A will add 2 new records that will change a lot of the 
computations on `overview_route`. User B submit those records and a 
background process fires to go and delete the records that need to be 
changed and and then gets rebuilt.

User A will go check `overview_route` to see the updated date, 
however can not even load the page and gets an application error.

User A can check back in 3-5 minutes (hopefully) and the page can be 
served again.
```

Example of rebuild logic being used:

```
def update(id)
  delete_keys("example:#{id}:current")
  delete_keys("example:#{id}:last_week")
  delete_keys("example:#{id}:start_of_week")
  ...
  rebuild(id)
end

def delete_keys(regex)
  $redis.scan_each(match: regex) do |key|
    $redis.del(key)
  end
end

#Basically loop through all records on a given model. If models 
#methods come across anything that isn't currently chached -- it will 
#set it back in redis
def rebuild(id)
  records = ModelExample.find(id)
  records.all.each do |a|
    a.rebuild
  end
  ...
end
```

**How do people handle this issue with numerous calls on unhandled methods cached typically (that are typically cached for performance)?**

I've tried/thought:

- Fixed the biggest N+1 queries within my model methods. This has helped a lot but still does not fix the timeout issue.
- Thought about existing add some sort of indiction on the Redis keys that one is the old data and add in the new (adding a is_stale to the keys). After new is completely added in delete the old data. The model methods could reference both keys and check for both Redis keys?
- Could I use some sort of dedup on Redis and then fail over? Not sure how this would be handled if I have a bunch of background jobs at once.
- I know there is a EXPIRE on Redis. Could I use something like this? How would I fail over to the new keys?
- Somehow don't delete any of the keys and just update them?

Comment: I don't know Redis but can you test if a certain cache is defined? If yes, then you can simply test if all the caches needed for you page to render are present. If not, render a simple "Caching all the data. Come back in 2 minutes", if yes, display the data.

Comment: I could do something like Redis.exists(key) on whats needed, I believe. However it becomes a problem if theres a numerous amount of records updated/submitted like lets say 32 within an hour, then it would take up to the point when everything is completed. Depends how many workers/threads I am able to supply tho.

Comment: You might want to kill all the existing caching update Threads every time there is an update that trigger this cache update.

Comment: This is a good idea for the short term -- I am also thinking maybe theres a way to persist the data in a fail over redis instance. Not sure if Sentinel can handle something like this though.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably a lot of ways to do this, but when I have code that takes a while to complete I run those tasks in the background. I would recommend Sidekiq http://sidekiq.org/. The free version should suffice for this.

It looks like you already have the logic in place, so I would just pass sidekiq the id and then move the logic to a worker. Something like

```
# app/worker/redis_worker.rb
class RedisWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  def perform(id)
    update(id)
  end
 ... Your logic
 def update(id)
   delete_keys("example:#{id}:current")
   delete_keys("example:#{id}:last_week")
   delete_keys("example:#{id}:start_of_week")
   ...
   rebuild(id)
 end

 def delete_keys(regex)
   $redis.scan_each(match: regex) do |key|
      $redis.del(key)
    end
  end

 def rebuild(id)
   records = ModelExample.find(id)
   records.all.each do |a|
     a.rebuild
   end
   ...
 end
end
```

to call this you would just call `RedisWorker.perform_async(id)`

Comment: I currently have this running as a sidekiq process. The issue really lies with when keys are deleted and then the route gets called. The route will then begin make calls against the DB instead of redis (thus calling all the methods and caching them while the sidekiq process is running) -- which I am trying to avoid.